# "Errno 2, No such file or directory" using Visual Studio Code on a MacBook

Tags: python

I have been trying to open a file from Visual Studio Code for a task, but it doesn't open. It always says "errno 2, no such file". I did open it once copying the path from the terminal, but it’s not working any more. I have tried many things that I have seen on Google Search or YouTube, but none have worked.

Right now I’ve been taught to open the file with this method:

```
file = open('input.txt', 'r+')
print(file)
```

Before I opened another file like this:

```
file = open('/Users/MYFULLNAME/Desktop/DOB.txt', 'r+')
print(file)
```

But this method isn't working any more. How can I fix it?

Comment: The second method should work. Is the file in your Desktop folder?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is not with Visual Studio Code, but rather with the path that you are defining to open the text file.

I'm assuming (from your second code snippet) your OS is Windows. You need to go to the location where you kept the text file. Right click on the file and select "Copy as path". This will copy the exact location of the file including its name and extension.

Once copied, you can paste the path to the following code:

```
with open("/path/you/copied", 'r') as file:  # make sure to replace '\' with '/' in the path
    print(file.readlines()) # this will print out all the lines in your text file in a list
    lines = file.readlines() # this will store all the lines in your text file as a list
    file.close() # this will ensure the text file in your HDD does not get corrupted
```

Now if you want to access each line from your text file, you can simply call the index in the list you created earlier by the following:

```
line_1 = lines[0]
line_2 = lines[1]
```

You can also get a bit more detailed explanations [here.](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/read-file-python/)